# How to get JSON output with Coffeescript?

Tags: json, coffeescript, slack-api, hubot

I have integrated Hubot with elasticsearch and slack.
When we are querying on the API, we are getting the output in JSON format when we use postman.

When we are querying from slack with coffeescript,we are getting plain output.
Here is the code

````
showHealth = (msg) ->
      msg.send("Getting the health for the cluster: ")
      msg.http("http://show-acc.com/_cluster/health/")
        .get() (err, res, body) ->
          lines = body.split("\n")
          header = lines.shift()
          list = [header].concat(lines.sort().reverse()).join("\n")
          msg.send("/code \n ```#{list}```")
````

This is printing me plain output in slack.
Could you please anyone help me how to change the code to print the output as JSON format?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to specify `"mrkdwn": true`, which will allow you to use backticks for code blocks. However, IMO the nicest way to achieve formatted messages is using Attachments, the structure of which is an array with hashed properties...

I've also got more mileage using `robot.messageRoom` rather than `msg.send`, something like this:

````
# Create attachment
msg = {
  attachments: [
    {
      fallback: 'Getting the health for the cluster: http://show-acc.com/_cluster/health/'
      title: 'Getting the health for the cluster:'
      title_link: 'http://show-acc.com/_cluster/health/'
      text: '/code \n ```#{list}```'
      mrkdwn_in: ['text']
    }
  ]
}
# Assign channel
channel = process.env.NOTIFY_ROOM

# Send it!
robot.messageRoom channel, msg
````

See the following refs for further info:

- https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting#message_formatting
- https://api.slack.com/docs/message-attachments